# mobile_app_install extracted from Facebook Insights API is different from the dashboard

Tags: python, facebook-business-sdk, facebook-python-business-sdk

I want to extract **mobile_app_install** but the numbers I have got from API seems not correct. It's 1839 by API using Python vs. 1736  in the dashboard. Any advice for this?

```
campaign = Campaign('23850184438290054')
fields = {'campaign_id','campaign_name','clicks', 'spend','cpc','cpm','ctr','actions'}
params = {
    # 'date_preset':'yesterday'
    'time_range':{'since':'2022-07-28','until':'2022-07-28'}
    # ,'breakdowns':'country'
    ,'level':'campaign'
    ,'time_increment':1
    ,'export_format':'csv'
    }
response = campaign.get_insights(params=params, fields = fields)
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response)
df.head()
```

[image: Python]

[image: dashboard]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

Add `'action_attribution_windows':'1d_click'` for android or `'action_attribution_windows':'skan_click'` for ios in the params

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).